# r How to get columns names based on a row criteria for ALL rows

Tags: r

I would like to create a variable which concatenates for each row the column names where we have the `TRUE` modality.

I tried

```
names(mat2)[mat2[i,]==TRUE]
```

but it isn't working.
Here are my data :

```
# dput(data)
structure(list(Object1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Object2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object3 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Object4 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    Object5 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object6 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object7 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), Object8 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object9 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object10 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
    Object11 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object12 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Object13 = c(FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), Object14 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Object15 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), Object16 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    )), .Names = c("Object1", "Object2", "Object3", "Object4", 
"Object5", "Object6", "Object7", "Object8", "Object9", "Object10", 
"Object11", "Object12", "Object13", "Object14", "Object15", "Object16"
), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here my dataframe with color (I put 1 color for the `TRUE` modality) :

[image]

I want to obtain a new variable like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
data$NewColumn <- apply(data, 1, FUN = function(x) paste(names(x)[x], collapse=' '))
```

Comment: Fantastic, it's working ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: thanks for the link ! Done